# android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout error

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

How can i fix this red line? **android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout error** did i miss something in my dependencies ?

[image]

[image]

```
this is my dependencies 

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
}
```

Comment: Import the widgets from androidx or add the design support library in your dependencies. You should always add the error in the question itself and not in an image.

Comment: how do i import the Import the widgets from androidx?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use **`androidx`** component

Use

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

Instead of

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

Use

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Instead of

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

Use

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Instead of

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

For `FloatingActionButton` use

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
```