# AppBarMainBinding.java / ContentMainBindind.java build error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-databinding

I try to build my app and I got stack-off errors.

Example `AppBarMainBinding.java` error:

> C:\My_App\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\example\My_App\databinding\AppBarMainBinding.java:4:

error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist
`import android.support.design.widget.^CoordinatorLayout;` (^displays an error item)

### AppBarMainBinding.java

files under the 'build' folder are generated and should not be edited

```
// Generated by view binder compiler. Do not edit!
package com.example.gym_app.databinding;

import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding;
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBindings;
import com.example.gym_app.R;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.String;

public final class AppBarMainBinding implements ViewBinding {
  @NonNull
  private final CoordinatorLayout rootView;

  @NonNull
  public final FloatingActionButton fab;

  @NonNull
  public final Toolbar toolbar;

  private AppBarMainBinding(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout rootView, @NonNull FloatingActionButton fab,
      @NonNull Toolbar toolbar) {
    this.rootView = rootView;
    this.fab = fab;
    this.toolbar = toolbar;
  }

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public CoordinatorLayout getRoot() {
    return rootView;
  }

  @NonNull
  public static AppBarMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return inflate(inflater, null, false);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static AppBarMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup parent, boolean attachToParent) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_bar_main, parent, false);
    if (attachToParent) {
      parent.addView(root);
    }
    return bind(root);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static AppBarMainBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
    // The body of this method is generated in a way you would not otherwise write.
    // This is done to optimize the compiled bytecode for size and performance.
    int id;
    missingId: {
      id = R.id.fab;
      FloatingActionButton fab = ViewBindings.findChildViewById(rootView, id);
      if (fab == null) {
        break missingId;
      }

      id = R.id.toolbar;
      Toolbar toolbar = ViewBindings.findChildViewById(rootView, id);
      if (toolbar == null) {
        break missingId;
      }

      return new AppBarMainBinding((CoordinatorLayout) rootView, fab, toolbar);
    }
    String missingId = rootView.getResources().getResourceName(id);
    throw new NullPointerException("Missing required view with ID: ".concat(missingId));
  }
}
```

---

Example `ContentMainBindind.java` error:

(Same C:)
error: package android.support.constraint does not exist
`private final ^ConstraintLayout rootView;` (^displays an error item)

> symbol:   class ConstraintLayout

> location: class ContentMainBinding

### ContentMainBinging.java

"files under the 'build' folder are generated and should not be edited"

```
// Generated by view binder compiler. Do not edit!
package com.example.gym_app.databinding;

import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding;
import com.example.gym_app.R;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import java.lang.Override;

public final class ContentMainBinding implements ViewBinding {
  @NonNull
  private final ConstraintLayout rootView;

  private ContentMainBinding(@NonNull ConstraintLayout rootView) {
    this.rootView = rootView;
  }

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public ConstraintLayout getRoot() {
    return rootView;
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ContentMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return inflate(inflater, null, false);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ContentMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup parent, boolean attachToParent) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, parent, false);
    if (attachToParent) {
      parent.addView(root);
    }
    return bind(root);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ContentMainBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
    if (rootView == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("rootView");
    }

    return new ContentMainBinding((ConstraintLayout) rootView);
  }
}
```

---

### build.grandle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gym_app"
        minSdk 31
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        compileSdkVersion 31
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.3.4'
    implementation 'org.web3j:compat:4.6.0-android'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
}
```

---

### grande.proprties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding\=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Your gradle.properties is the default one. (No problem exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler can't find some classes from the `android.support` package. This is probably because you want to use `androidx` but referenced the wrong package in your layout xml.

Make sure, you use the Views and Widgets from the `androidx` package in your layout xml.

Also update all `android.arch` dependencies to their latest `androidx` equivalent.

Comment: That's not layout xml error. ...binding.java build scripts that you can't edit. I tried add, example `androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout`, but it give me error-`Supplied String module notation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout' is invalid.`

Comment: That looks like a missing depenency. Could you share at least parts of your layout xml?

Comment: I didn't knew that there is app_bar_main xml... I think that was some android studios error but now it work.

I found that solution.

I just wondering why it show error Binding script?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62424812/android-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout-error

Comment: It shows the error in the binding because the binding is generated from the xml using the same classes/views/widgets as specified in the xml.
It doesn't do sanity check yet. Then comes the compiler and wonders where those classes are defined.
Trying to use the wrong classes fails at the latest at runtime when the views are inflated